# how to store list of word and numbers in a file

Tags: python

I want to assign numbers to words (starting from one) and create two lists, one of the words, one of the numbers. Then create a file and store both lists in it. So far I have:

```
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
list_of_words = sentence.split()
words_with_numbers = enumerate(list_of_words, start=1)
```

Comment: How will the file be structured?  Will it contain one list and then the other?  If so, how will you know where one list stops and the other starts?

Comment: So is your question "How do I write to a file in Python"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try (if this is what you want) is:

```
sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
list_of_words = sentence.split()
words_with_numbers = enumerate(list_of_words, start=1)
filename = 'yourfilename.txt'
with open(filename, 'w+') as file:
    file.write(str(list_of_words) + '\n' + str(words_with_numbers) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `open` a file and write to it

```
In [1]: sentence = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
Please enter a sentence: Hello World

In [2]: with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(), start=1):
   ...:         f.write("{} {}\n".format(i, word))
   ...:
```

Then

```
$ cat output.txt
1 Hello
2 World
```